# Show that $y(x)= \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}dt$ satisfies the differential equation $y^{(2)}+2xy^{(1)}=0$.

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, differential

Show that  $y(x)= \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}dt$ satisfies the differential equation
$y^{(2)}+2xy^{(1)}=0$.

Comment: Have you tried differentiating $y$ using Liebniz integral rule then substituting back into the DE?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for starters 
$$
y(x)= \int_x^\infty e^{-t^2}dt=-\int^x_\infty e^{-t^2}dt
$$
so by the fundamental theorem of calculus 
$$
y'(x)=-e^{-x^2}, y''(x)=2x e^{-x^2}
$$

and it is easy to check that
$$
y''+2xy=0
$$